# How to print out encoded Asian characters(gb2312) on command prompt?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, command-prompt

I am working for a company that uses the Python programming language version 3.1 as a causal work now.
And I've encountered this problem: how to print out some encoded Asian characters(Chinese, Japanese, Korean) on command prompt?

Done a bit research and tried, but got no luck:

```
import sys
import codecs
print(sys.getdefaultencoding()) # prints out UTF-8
fileObj = codecs.open("test.txt", "r", "eucgb2312_cn")
content = fileObj.read()
print(content)
```

It is the last line that would cause this error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Michael Mao\Desktop>test.py
utf-8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Michael Mao\Desktop\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(u)
  File "C:\tools\Python31\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u5377' in position 3: character maps to < undefined >
```

I cannot change the default encoding from UTF-8 to anything else, so I reckon that is the problem preventing the output from being rendered correctly.

Can anyone help me out in this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can I have some texts from your test.txt?

Comment: Well, I just grab some workds from online news written in Chinese and save it to disk as with the GB2312 encoding...

Comment: Oh, as S.Mark suggested, I tried to use print(content.encode("u8")
 and print(content.encode('eucgb2312_cn')) but both got me some weird output as:

xd5\xc2\xbd\xda\xb8\xfc\xb6\xe0\xa3\xac\xd6\xa7\xb3\xb3\xd6\xd5\xfd\xb0\xe6\xd4\xc4\xb6\xc1\xa3\xa1)\r\n'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem. When I am programming a dict, I encounter this problem.

```
#coding=utf-8
import codecs
import sys
# import imp
# imp.reload(sys) 
# sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
dictFileName = 'abstract.dict'
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())  
print(sys.stdout.encoding)

def readDict():
    print("start reading dict...")
    #dictObject = codecs.open(dictFileName,'rb', encoding = 'utf-8')#, encoding = 'utf-8')
    dictObject = open(dictFileName, 'rb')
    try:
        print('open file success!')
        #dictObject.seek(0x1852c)
        chunk = dictObject.read(0x5f0) #0x5f0
        print(len(chunk))
        #chunk = dictObject.read(0x1)
        print('read success')
        #print(chunk.decode("utf-8"))
        #print(chunk.encode('utf-8').decode('gb18030'))
        #sys.stdout.buffer.write(chunk.encode('gb18030'))
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(chunk.decode('utf-8').encode('gb18030'))
    finally:
        dictObject.close()
readDict()
input()
```

Comment: I think the key is :sys.stdout.buffer.write(chunk.encode('gb18030'))

Comment: ps:codecs.open(dictFileName,'r', encoding = 'utf-8'),encoding = 'utf-8' is essential.

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot change the default encoding from UTF-8 to anything else

I don't think UTF-8 is being used as the default encoding for your console:

> File "C:\tools\Python31\lib\encodings\cp437.py"

cp437 is the old DOS terminal code page, which indeed cannot print chinese characters.

See [bug 1602](http://bugs.python.org/issue1602) for a batch file hack to make Windows and Python 3 use UTF-8 (code page 65001) for the console, but in general the console has always been pretty broken for non-ASCII characters, and will continue to be so until someone changes Python to use WriteConsoleW instead of the standard C IO functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the cmd window yourself, type the following command before running test.py:
mode con cp select=936

If your Python program starts by some other means, you'll have to make it open its console window with the correct code page.